Constant expression required error with visa32.dll included in VB6 project references
I have downloaded and included the VISA library in my VB6 project through visa32.dll. When I try to compile the project, I get this error message:

Constant expression required


The VISA library is included in the project references here:

Here is VI_NULL in visa32.dll:

Why am I getting the error for VI_NULL but not VI_SUCCESS which is just above it?

Take in account that there are different VISA libraries. From NI, from Keysight, from IVI foundation... Make sure you are using the right one.

I used my company's installer for NI but I'm not sure how to tell if the library is from NI or IVI Foundation. It installed both an NI and IVI Foundation directory to my program files, and visa32.dll is (obviously) in the SYSWOW64 directory.

My experience is that using visa32 in modern 64bit OS is a nightmare. Try making it work in a Virtual Environment with a 32 bit OS. Then if you manage to make it work there try porting it to a more modern 64 bit OS.

Would pointing the library reference to the visa32.dll in the System32 directory possibly fix it?

You need to provide more info. The popup message is not enough, there should be a complete traceback of the error. It looks like somewhere a constant is required, so you have to investigate where, and what are you passing instead. Check what is the value of VI_NULL, maybe it's not refering to a constant but a null pointer. Trye changing it for something else to see if this particular error disapears. The you will know that the error is indeed caused by VI_NULL
